# Getting specific properties from a list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am facing a problem

i have a class

```
public class StudentDetails
{    
    int S_Detail_ID;
    string address;
    string email;    
}
```

containg get set method and  iam calling a function which is collecting the `List<StudentDetails>` and showing it in datagridview the problem is that list is returning all properties of the class, but i only want address and email not s_detail_id

here is code for the function

```
private void btnAddNewRowInGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    List<StudentDetails> lstStudentDetails = GetStudentDetails();
    lststudentDetails.Add(new StudentDetails()); //what to do here, studentDetails is returning all properties but i want only addres and email
    dataGridView1.DataSource = lstStudentDetails;
}
```

and  GetStudent jusst count rows in datagridview and add a new row

```
private List<StudentDetails> GetStudentDetails()
{
    lstStudentDetails = new List<StudentDetails>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {

        lstStudentDetails.Add(row.DataBoundItem as StudentDetails);
    }
    return lstStudentDetails;
}
```

Comment: You can either a) hide some of the datagridview columns or b) use a Linq `.Select` query to only return the properties you want to display - which to use depends on  whether you want to be able to access the Student ID from the datagridview?

Comment: @stuartd thanks sir for providing useful solution. i followed hiding column just by adding line **dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false; ** and the problem is solved but i would like to ask you if you provide some details about solution b. earlier i have done **lstStudentDetails.Select( address => sd.Address()).toList()** but it does not solve the problem

Comment: @HassaanKhan why bound columns and then hide them? Its better not to bound columns which you don't need

Answer (score 3):

1. Select DataGridView in designer and click on little triangle at top right corner of control
2. Click *Edit Columns* menu item
3. Manually add columns for address and email properties (type in property name in DataPropertyName item of column properties)
4. Disable columns auto-generation

[image]

You cannot turn off columns auto-generation from designer - its possible only from code:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

After that your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try hiding the column you do not need by setting its visibility to false.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["S_Detail_ID"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: if you check my comment above i have already done this. here i am trying to explore the list.select() projection